What is good practice to change GCC version?
I'm looking to upgrade my gcc version from 6.3.0 (Debian 9) to 8.3.0 (Debian 10). However, when I tested gcc 8.3.0, I found that it broke one of my loops when using -ftree-loop-vectorize. My workaround for now is to encapsulate the loop in a function and disable vectorization.
However, I'm concerned that my testing might not cover all potential issues, and there could be other stuffs that are broken by the upgrade.
What would be the good practice for handling this situation (and the general situation of changing compiler version)?
From comments: I want to detect the broken code when changing compilers. More precisely, I do have two answers "do not change your compiler" and "pray the Gods", I am asking whether there is other ways.

What would be the best practice for handling this situation? Most probably you have a bug in your code. The best practice is triple checking your code for bugs.

@KamilCuk thanks, I mean is there any good practice in checking my code for bugs? Also let me change "best practice" to "good practice".

Please post a minimal reproducible example of a program that exhibits the problem.

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I can't sorry. However, I can say that my problem relates to this bug of negative stride https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92420 (there are examples in the link) which has been fixed in GCC 8.4.0. And I am not allowed to use GCC 8.4.0 in my platform Debian 10.

Consider installing Nix (https://nixos.org/) as a secondary package manager -- everything it installs lives under /nix/store and won't modify distro-provided files. Using Nix in "pure" mode, an environment it sets up for you will only contain locations from that store, making the versions of distro-provided packages entirely moot.

@KamilCuk sorry I did not understand your comment. No, the bug is in GCC 8.3.0 because GCC 8.4 works perfectly for my code. The GCC bug is https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92420 and I am not allowed to use GCC 8.4.0.

So your question is actually "what are good practices for handling known and long-fixed bugs when you're not allowed to upgrade to the version with the fix?"

@JosephSible-ReinstateMonica yes, but by "handling" I mean only detect the broken code. Even if I were able to use GCC 8.4.0, the version with the fix, is there any methodology to test? More precisely, I do have two answers "do not change your compiler" and "pray the Gods", I am looking for other ways people have used to handle this situation.

Unit tests are for detecting such bugs.

If you have code that is known to fail for certain compiler versions, you can #if ...-guard it with compiler version macros and some workaround code. To detect such issues have a unit test suite with good code coverage.
